# AEM Communities Cleanup SRP - Bundle status is not Active

Tags: aem

I cloned project from [here](https://github.com/andrewmkhoury/communities-srp-tools). And I imported in eclipse as maven project and trying to build it using **mvn clean install -DskipTests**. 
After deploying getting **com.day.cq.commons- cannot resolve** error in system console. For this I checked in depfinder there is already following dependency is present[image].

Please help me. I'm new in AEM.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the full error, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve above problem after importing following package in maven-bundle-plugin in pom.xml

```
<Import-Package>com.day.cq.commons;version=5.7.6;</Import-Package>
```

So, whole story will look like following:

```
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.0</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
          <configuration>
            <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
            <instructions>
              <Bundle-Category>social</Bundle-Category>
              <Bundle-DocURL>
                http://www.adobe.com
              </Bundle-DocURL>
              <Bundle-Vendor>Adobe Systems Inc.</Bundle-Vendor>
              <Import-Package>com.day.cq.commons;version=5.7.6;</Import-Package>
            </instructions>
          </configuration>
```